# How to allow blank lines for xml-formatter in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting

Is there a way in Eclipse formatter for xml-files to allow maximum of one blank line. I could not find the proper option. Like:

```
<a>
  <b>
  ...
  </b>
  <!-- keep this line as a blank line -->
  <c>
  ...
  </c>
</a>
<!-- keep this line as a blank line -->
<d>
...
</>
```

With default properties and ctrl+shift+f the blank lines get deteled. Or has this something to do with well-formed xml?

Comment: There's no such thing as "well-formatted XML". Every formatter does what it thinks is best. Most offer only very limited control over the output.

Comment: Sorry, I meant well-formed xml.

Comment: Well, the amount of whitespace between elements doesn't affect whether it's well-formed or not.

Comment: How about empty lines?

Comment: Since having upgraded from m2e 1 to 2, this also happens in the POM editor - very highly annoying! I don't find any setting to turn this off....

Comment: Probably related to this: https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/1006

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, there is a setting under `XML / XML Files / Editor` to `Clear all blank lines`. Turning that off should keep the empty lines.

Comment: ... however, it is turned off on my system and I still get empty lines removed in Eclipse 2022-12 with m2e 2 in the POM editor ...